# How to fix cucumber step does not have matching glue code?

Tags: cucumber, junit, bdd

The cucumber feature file has all steps highlighted in yellow and warning is shown as step does not have matching glue code, When I try to run the project as maven test, I am getting null pointer exception for all steps.

[TestRunner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csGDS.png)[Feature[Steps[image: ][2]]

[image: Login.feature]

Test Runner class:

```
package com.vtiger.CucumberFramework.testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
                features = "classpath:features",
                glue = {"com.vtiger.CucumberFramework.stepDefinitions","com.vtiger.CucumberFramework.testRunner"}, 
                plugin = { "pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty", 
                           "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                           "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt" },
                monochrome = true)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Not a Cucumber expert, but you have a space before the $ in your step definitions. Maybe it is causing the pattern to not match. (If that's the case, I will transform this comment in an answer to be accepted)

Comment: What is the exact exception? Maybe the driver is not created in your TestBase

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have installed cucumber for eclipse from market place:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-eclipse-plugin

Goto preference and search for cucumber and enable step detection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "glue" Cucumber option specifies the package where the step definition files are located. I don't think you need the runner package.

Try this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
                features = "classpath:features",
                glue = "com.vtiger.CucumberFramework.stepDefinitions", 
                plugin = { "pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty", 
                           "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                           "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt" },
                monochrome = true)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: runner package  has cucumber hooks , so that is needed. without that my "@Before" and '@After' hooks wont run

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue occasionally, Cucumber files fail to point to the associated step definition files even if it was working flawlessly previously.

One little hack is to go to the associated step definition class -> Make a harmless/Dummy modification -> Save the class file.

Now the eclipse feature files have no "Step does not have matching glue code" errors.